# How to set default value for host directive's @Input without overriding the actual value?

Tags: angular

I'm using a directive to share inputs between different types of form controls:

```
@Directive({
  standalone: true
})
export class SDKControlMixin {
  ...
  @Input() iconSide: 'left' | 'right' = 'left';
}
```

Which is then used as a host directive:

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  ...
  hostDirectives: [
    {
      directive: SDKControlMixin,
      inputs: [
        ...
        'iconSide'
      ]
    }
  ]
})
export class LibInputSearchComponent {

  constructor(private controlMixin: SDKControlMixin) {
    super();
    
    this.controlMixin.iconSide = 'right';
  }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that it doesn't seem possible to assign default values to a host directive like this. Even if I use the `LibInputSearchComponent` component like this:

```
<lib-input-search iconSide="left"></lib-input-search>
```

The value of `iconSide` will always be `'right'`, since that's what's being set in the constructor. I can't set default values to `SDKControlMixin`'s constructor either since you don't manually call `super` for it, like you do with extended classes.

I don't want to use an extended class either because it exposes properties in the component's API that might not be supported in the component, which is confusing for the consumers of the components.

Is there a way to set default values for a host directive while still allowing the value passed through the input to override it?

Comment: seems this should've been a base feature